# Notice: Undefined index: id in views_ctools_field_views_data()

Tags: 7, views, chaos-tool-suite

I have the [Views Ctools Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_ctools_field) module installed.
I am getting below errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in views_ctools_field_views_data() (line 66 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/views_ctools_field/views_ctools_field.views.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: key in views_ctools_field_views_data() (line 67 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/views_ctools_field/views_ctools_field.views.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: id in views_ctools_field_views_data() (line 66 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/views_ctools_field/views_ctools_field.views.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: key in views_ctools_field_views_data() (line 67 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/views_ctools_field/views_ctools_field.views.inc).
```

**EDIT:**

Actually this module is installed by others in production site.

I am theming a views table for a specific content type.Its working fine. I thought these errors are because of the view table theming which I have created.
But these are occuring while clearing the cache also.
But when we referesh the page these errors could not be seen again.

I am also using custom module to hide some fields using hook_form_alter and set the values using hook_node_presave and the custom module is also working fine.

I am not using views ctool field.

Not able to understand why these errors are occurring.

What can be done to remove these notices?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Provide some more information about the install and where exactly you use Views Ctools Field. It would also be good to notice if you are using custom or forked modules.

Comment: @Topsitemakers: Please see my edit.

Comment: I'd say to go with a standard debugging recipe: clone the site and try disabling the module/theme to narrow down where the issue might be. Nothing comes to my mind from what you posted and there might be other things that influence this.